# CSS/HTML - Change position of a certain part of a <p> using <span> not working as intended

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the "fact" part further to the left than the remaining text. I figured this would do the job but for some reason the "fact" doesn't move at all. What's the problem here? (I'm using Chrome, not sure if that is relevant).

```
<head>
      <style>
       #fact0{
         position: absolute;
         top: 10%;
         left: 20%;
       }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p id="fact0"> <span style = "left: 36%;"> Fact: </span> <br></br> Paris is the capital of France. </p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get it all on the same line? What are you going for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "fact" span is statically positioned (i.e. it has the default value "static" set for its "position" property) inside its parent paragraph. By being statically positioned, it is not affected by the "left" property that you set to 36%.

If you want it to be affected by the "left" property, set its "position" property to "relative":

```html
<head>
      <style>
       #fact0{
         position: absolute;
         top: 10%;
         left: 20%;
       }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p id="fact0"> <span style = "left: 36%; position: relative;"> Fact: </span> <br></br> Paris is the capital of France. </p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Oh right this makes alot more sence than some of the other answers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```css
#fact0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
}
#fact0 span {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id="fact0"> <span> Fact: </span>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
```

Update based on comment

Sample 2

```css
#fact0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
}
#fact0 span {
  position: relative;
  left: -36%;
}
```

```html
<p id="fact0"> <span> Fact: </span>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I'm however very confused. If I were to want to change the color of Fact I could use <span style = "color: blue;"> Fact: </span> and it would work. What's the difference when I want to change it's position?

Comment: @JoeJacksson There is no, though when it comes to moving an inline element, such as a `span`, it needs more styling.

Comment: I think Eric MORAND explained it. The span is positioned to static and has to be manually changed to relative for it to work as intended, which makes alot of sence.

Comment: Without "position:absolute", your element is in a static position, which is the default. Only elements with position relative, absolute or fixed are influenced by top/bottom/left/right. Here's a complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: relative` on the `span`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could also try something like this:

```
<p id="fact0"> <span style ="position:relative;margin-left:-36%;"> Fact: </span> <br></br> Paris is the capital of France. </p>
```